# How to make a group of polygons larger?

Tags: arcmap

I need to edit the vertices of about 30 polygons in an equal way, how would I go about this? Alternatively is there some method to just increase the size of a group of polygons 200%?

Comment: Good question.  I hadn't heard of scaling before - it should be part of the buffer tool in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is possible using the scale tool:

http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Scaling_features

It might not be enabled by default, so you can turn it on.

Here's a tutorial of how it works:

http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/tutorials/editor/Editor_Ex4_5.htm

Failing this you could always do a buffer and then union the output with the original file, although this a bit of a 'dirty fix'

Comment: I can't find scale in 10?

Comment: I think one way I can get around it - not preffered though - is as I am using data driven pages I can change the extent of my grids..I think

Comment: 10:
To use the Scale tool, you must first add it to an ArcMap toolbar from the Commands tab of the Customize dialog box. The Scale tool  is found in the Editor category. 
Click the Edit tool  on the Editor toolbar. 
Click the feature that you want to scale. 
Click the Scale tool  on the toolbar to which you added it. 
Move the selection anchor (the x), if necessary, since the feature is scaled based on the selection anchor's location. 
Drag the pointer over the feature to scale it, or press the F key to set a scale factor. 
Release the mouse button when you are finished scaling the feature.

Comment: I can't seem to add it? nothing happens when I click the scale button and check my editor box